# Partials for Collection of Rails Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, partials

I have a collection of 3 types of objects, Posts, Products, and Content. I want to put all of these objects into a feed and order them by when they were created. I've done all that. The issue I'm having is I want to have a different partial for each item. How would I do that?

Here's the controller action getting all the objects:

```
 @stream = current_user.stream
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this if each item has it own class:

```
@stream.each do |item|    
  render item
end
```

Or this if there is a field "kind" for the objects:

```
@stream.each do |item|    
  render item.kind
end
```

and create the following partials:

```
_post.html.erb
_product.html.erb
_content.html.erb
```

Just be sure that those files are on the correct view folder